# Golang: int to slice conversion

Tags: indexing, go, slice

Total golang (and programming) noob!

Given any six digit number, how could one output a slice where each character of that number is assigned an individual location within the slice?

For instance, a slice (let's call it s) containing all of these characters, would have s[0]=first digit, s[1]=second digit, s[2]=third digit and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not use string? https://play.golang.org/p/72Zs58FbJd

Answer (score 7):

```golang
func IntToSlice(n int64, sequence []int64) []int64 {
    if n != 0 {
        i := n % 10
        // sequence = append(sequence, i) // reverse order output
        sequence = append([]int64{i}, sequence...)
        return IntToSlice(n/10, sequence)
    }
    return sequence
}
```

Comment: Please add at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to convert `12345` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
Am I not right?

Comment: This is a good answer - but it reverses the order.
To preserve the initial order, use `sequence = append([]int{i}, s...)` , instead.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are correct. Here comes another version of MBB's answer.
Avoiding recursion and efficient reverting may increase performance and reduce RAM consumption.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func reverseInt(s []int) {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
            s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
}

func splitToDigits(n int) []int{
    var ret []int
    
    for n !=0 {
        ret = append(ret, n % 10)
        n /= 10
    }
    
    reverseInt(ret)
    
    return ret
}

func main() {
    for _, n := range splitToDigits(12345) {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/M3aOUnNIbdv

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process, first converting int to string, then iterating the string or converting to a slice. Because the built in range function lets you iterate each character in a string, I recommend keeping it as a string. Something like this;

```
 import "strconv"
 str := strconv.Itoa(123456)
 for i, v := range str {
      fmt.Println(v) //prints each char's ASCII value on a newline
      fmt.Printf("%c\n", v) // prints the character value
 }
```

Comment: @MDrollette: ranging over a string returns runes http://play.golang.org/p/hiqax-cmh8

Comment: @JimB I assume you would need to convert to `[]rune` if you wanted to index into the string directly and not via a `range`? https://play.golang.org/p/kFhQXUD4Ay

Comment: @MDrollette in general yes (if you want to index by rune/characters rather than by bytes). However, coming from `strconv.Itoa` you know each rune will be a single byte and so directly indexing the string will give the exact same values (i.e. in this example `rune(str[3]) == []rune(str)[3]`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why nobody mentioned this way:
(No need recursion)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    n := 3456
    fmt.Println(NumToArray(n))
    fmt.Println(NumToArray2(n))
}

func NumToArray(num int) []int {
    arr := make([]int, len(strconv.Itoa(num)))

    for i := len(arr) - 1; num > 0; i-- {
        arr[i] = num % 10
        num = int(num / 10)
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)
    return arr
}

// Without converting to string
func NumToArray2(num int) (arr []int) {
    for num > 0 {
        arr = append(arr, num%10)
        num = int(num / 10)
    }
    // Reverse array to the rigtht order
    for i, j := 0, len(arr)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)
    return arr
}
```

P.S. Benchmarks are welcome

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you can convert your int value to string and after that you can use split function which is under strings library.I hope below code will work for you!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
  "strings"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
  num:=10101
  a:=strconv.Itoa(num)
  res:=strings.Split(a,"")
  fmt.Println("The value of res is",res)
  fmt.Printf("The type of res is %T\n",res)
  
  fmt.Println(res[0])
}
```

> Output:  The value of res is [1 0 1 0 1]
> The type of res is []string 1